# Multiple source files into one zip

Tags: set, backup

How to create one zip file, using this destinations?
Now it makes an archive only with *.txt files, how to add all another destinations? Thanks.

```
set source="{GameHomeDir}\server\cfg\*"
set source="{GameHomeDir}\server\save\*"
set source="{GameHomeDir}\server\*.map"
set source="{GameHomeDir}\server\*.map.sav"
set source="{GameHomeDir}\server\*.txt"

set dest="{GameHomeDir}\server\backup\%zipfilename%"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please take a minute to read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe [Writing the perfect question.](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

What have you tried? 
What specifically do you want to achieve? 
What environment do you need to achieve this in?

Comment: `set` may be overwriting the previous `source` variables, you say it is making the archive with only `*.txt` files, could this be because it is the last `set source` command? see line 5 of your first example